# Retrieve content using two labels with Casperjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, casperjs

I'm just starting with CasperJs and I'd like to retrieve the current page number which is stored in a list. I assume this can be done by combining the `class` and the `aria-selected` which must be true to indicate the current page.

I would appreciate if someone can point out how to do this programmatically.
Here's what I've got so far:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:23.0) Gecko/20130404 Firefox/23.0"
    }
});

var url = 'https://markets.ft.com/data/director-dealings';
var currentPage = 1;
var jobs = [];

casper.start(url, function() {
    this.waitForSelector('li[class="mod-ui-pagination__number"]');
});

casper.then(function() {

    var el = document.querySelectorAll('body > div.o-grid-container.mod-container > div:nth-child(2) > section > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.mod-ui-pagination__results-count > ul');//div[3] div[2] section div[1] div div div[3] ul li[2]');

    this.echo(JSON.stringify(el)); 
});

casper.run();
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="mod-ui-pagination">
    <li class="mod-ui-pagination__arrows" aria-disabled="false"><i class="o-ft-icons-icon o-ft-icons-icon--arrow-left"></i></li>
    <li class="mod-ui-pagination__number" aria-selected="false" data-mod-pagination-num="1">1</li>
    <li class="mod-ui-pagination__number" aria-selected="true" data-mod-pagination-num="2">2</li>
    <li class="mod-ui-pagination__number" aria-selected="false" data-mod-pagination-num="3">3</li>
    <li class="mod-ui-pagination__ellipsis"><i class="o-ft-icons-icon o-ft-icons-icon--more"></i></li>
    <li class="mod-ui-pagination__number" aria-selected="false" data-mod-pagination-num="739">739</li>
    <li class="mod-ui-pagination__number" aria-selected="false" data-mod-pagination-num="740">740</li>
    <li class="mod-ui-pagination__number" aria-selected="false" data-mod-pagination-num="741">741</li>
    <li class="mod-ui-pagination__arrows" aria-disabled="false"><i class="o-ft-icons-icon o-ft-icons-icon--arrow-right"></i></li>
</ul>
```

PS: Is there a trick to quickly find how to access an element? Inspect > Copy Selector

Edit: Inspect > Copy Xpath returns this for the ul element: `html/body/div[3]/div[2]/section/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `evaluate()` to access the real page environment (DOM)
2. Use `querySelector()` instead of `querySelectorAll()` because you just need one element
3. Use this CSS selector: `ul.mod-ui-pagination > li[aria-selected="true"]`

Here is the script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  pageSettings: {
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:23.0) Gecko/20130404 Firefox/23.0'
  }
});

casper.start('https://markets.ft.com/data/director-dealings');

casper.waitForSelector('li.mod-ui-pagination__number', function () {
  this.echo(this.evaluate(function () {
    var el = document.querySelector('ul.mod-ui-pagination > li[aria-selected="true"]');
    return el.textContent;
  }));
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I appreciate it, could you please clarify the following points:  1. Why evaluate and not simply access directly the DOM?  2. How did you get the CSS selector?

Comment: 1. When you run a CasperJS script on PhantomJS or SlimerJS, you are in a specific environment and do not have access to the DOM. Outside `evaluate`, `this` refers to `casper`. Inside `evaluate`, `this` refers to `window`. You can have more info [here](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate). 2. I built this selector by hand, according to your needs. `ul.mod-ui-pagination` is important to target the pagination (which is a list). `>` says that we want direct children only (`li`). Finally, `li[aria-selected="true"]` gives you the selected `li`; exactly what you want...